# How to define unspecified constants in Coq

Tags: coq

My question is how to define unspecified constants in Coq. 
To make clear what I mean, assume the following toy system:
I want to define a function 
f:nat->nat, which has the value 0 at all but one place w, where it has the value 1.
The place w shall be a parameter of the system.
All proofs of the system can assume that w is fixed but arbitrary.

My idea was to introduce
Parameter w:nat.

But I get stuck by defining f(x), because I don't have a clue how to match x with a.

What would be the right way to handle this?
Or, is it the wrong way using w as a Parameter?

(This is NOT a homework question)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it:

```
Require Import Arith.

Parameter w : nat.
Definition f (n : nat) := if beq_nat n w then 1 else 0.
```

When proving properties about `f` you can then use lemmas specifying that `beq_nat n w` is indeed deciding whether `n = w`. You can find them by using e.g.

```
SearchAbout beq_nat.
```